# shortalphabetic bib style with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, amsrefs

The `amsrefs` package has the `shortalphabetic` style which is similar to `alphabetic` but less verbose (for example, the year is excluded). Is there any way to do that with `biblatex`?

Currently, I have

```
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backref=true, backend=biber, hyperref=true, giveninits=true]{biblatex}
```

And for .bib file, I have

```
@article{ben-zvi_character_2009,
  archivePrefix = {arXiv},
  eprinttype = {arxiv},
  eprint = {0904.1247},
  primaryClass = {math},
  date = {2009-04-07},
  keywords = {Geometric Satake,Representation theory,Geometric reps,Trace},
  author = {Ben-Zvi, David and Nadler, David}
}

@article{ben-zvi_integral_2010,
  langid = {american},
  title = {Integral Transforms and {{Drinfeld}} Centers in Derived Algebraic Geometry},
  volume = {23},
  issn = {0894-0347, 1088-6834},
  doi = {10.1090/S0894-0347-10-00669-7},
  number = {4},
  journaltitle = {Journal of the American Mathematical Society},
  shortjournal = {J. Amer. Math. Soc.},
  date = {2010},
  pages = {909-966},
  keywords = {DAG,Trace},
  author = {Ben-Zvi, David and Francis, John and Nadler, David}
}
```

The bibliography would appear like so

[image]

But if use `amsrefs` with `shortalphabetic` option

```
\usepackage[shortalphabetic]{amsrefs}
```

Bibliography would become

[image]

The main thing I like about the 2nd style (`amsrefs`) is that the keys (eg. [BZFN], [BZN]) don't include the years. It would be great to make `biblatex` produce [BFN] and [BN] instead of [BFN10] and [BN09].

Thanks!

Comment: It would really help if you could show us what you have so far and could point out *concrete* changes to the output you get. I'm not familiar with `shortalphabetic` and I doubt there will be an exact match in the arsenal of readily available `biblatex` styles, but `biblatex` is quite customisable and some things are done easily and more complicated things can be achieved with a bit more work.

Comment: @moewe Thanks! I added more concrete examples.

Comment: For arXiv articles that have not been published in a journal (yet) I usually recommend the type `@online` instead of `@article` since `@article`s usually expect a `journal` and a `volume` field, which those entries normally lack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is only about the alphabetic label, you will want to have a look at `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate`. The following takes the default definition from `biblatex`'s `alphabetic` style and removes the two digits from the year.

See also [§4.5.5 Labels of the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf#subsubsection.4.5.5), pp. 198-206.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backref=true, backend=biber, giveninits=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [GMS] M. Goossens, F. Mittelbach and A. Samarin. The LaTeX Companion. 1st ed. Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley, 1994. 528 pp. (cit. on p. 1).//[SR] E. Sigfridsson and U. Ryde. ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P (cit. on p. 1).]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply! Does this also do dedup automatically? Support before, I had [ABC18], [ABC19], would it become [ABCa] [ABCb] automatically?

Comment: @QcH It should. Why don't you try it out? In case you don't have example entries at hand, cite `knuth:ct:a` and `knuth:ct:b` from `biblatex-examples.bib`.

Comment: Awesome! It works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello, thank you @moewe for providing this solution. Any chance you can tell me how to obtain the same result, except I'd like to see [ABC1] [ABC2] instead of [ABCa] [ABCb]?

Comment: @Seub Try `\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{#1}`. If that does not work, I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: @moewe Works like a charm. Thank you very much